# Neither es6 nor es5 syntax allowed for imports in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, node-modules

I've been tripped up by the `No imports inside a module` error and similar errors more times than I can count. Honestly, I have no idea what it means and it seems to be pretty arbitrary as I've tried adding module rules, removing them, using only es5, using only es6, and nothing seems to be consistent.

Currently I'm trying to use the `cross-blob` package so I can save a raw SVG as a file, as `Blob` is not supported in es5 as far as I can tell. My functions are crashing with the following error:

`Must use import to load ES Module: /path/to/cross-blob require() of ES modules is not supported.`

I'm using that module as follows:

userActions.ts

```js
import { createAvatar } from "@dicebear/avatars"; // this worked fine
import * as style from "@dicebear/avatars-bottts-sprites"; // this worked fine
import Blob from "cross-blob"; // this did not

export const createNewProfileImage = () => {
  const profileImageSvg = createAvatar(style);
  const blob = new Blob([profileImageSvg], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
// more code
```

As you can see, no `require()`. It suggest I remove `"type": "module"` from my `package.json`, but it's not used in my package.json.

I'm then importing that fn into my `index.ts` file as follows:

index.js

```js
import { getBitcoinPrice, getAdviceSlip, getRandomAnimal } from "./callApis"; // works fine
import { createNewProfileImage } from "./userActions"; // works fine if I don't use cross-blob

const createNewUser = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .auth.user()
  .onCreate(async (user: UserRecord) => {
    const svg = createNewProfileImage();
// more code
```

I've also tried switching to `require` statements, but that then errors out with `Require statement not part of import statement.`

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "emulate": "npm run build -- --watch | firebase emulators:start --import ../db",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@dicebear/avatars": "^4.10.0",
    "@dicebear/avatars-bottts-sprites": "^4.10.0",
    "axios": "^0.23.0",
    "cross-blob": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please consider [specifying your dependencies.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-nodejs). Also can you please share your package.json file with us?

Comment: @RajeevTirumalasetty added package.json and tsconfig, as I know that can have an effect.

Comment: Can you please provide [build logs?](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/view-build-results#console)